# Where to property place registerForRemoteNotifications when playerviewcontroller no longer available

Tags: ios, notifications, avaudioplayer, avplayer

I have an app that has a MainViewController, a PlaylistViewController and a PlayerViewController.

All works just fine playing audio in the background when you return to the home screen.

The PlayerViewController, calls registerForRemoteNotifications in it's viewDidAppear to capture notifications from the Control Center and Headset controls. While this controller is in the foreground, notifications from control center / headset are received and pause/play work just fine.

HOWEVER, if return the the PlayListViewController or MainViewController while the audio is playing and then return to the Home Screen (audio is still playing as it should), however remote notifications from the Control Center are no longer sent to the PlayerViewController obviously because it is no longer around.

In order to do this, do I need to create static AVAudioPlayer objects in the AppDelegate vs the PlayerViewController and move the  registerForRemoteNotifications to the AppDelegate along with the logic from the PlayerViewController to handle Pause / Play from Control Center and headset devices and access the AppDelegates static objects in my PlayerViewController?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole remote notification logic is supposed to be located in the application delegate class, because that's the only class which is reliably alive during the application life cycle.

Since application delegate is accessible from everywhere using

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
```

you can create references to other classes or implement delegate methods to be able to handle the notifications properly.

Comment: So with that being said, the AVPlayer is created and controlled in the PlayerViewController.  How do I get the AppDelegate to call the pause / play functions of the PlayerViewController?

Comment: Sorry was being brain dead.  All I needed to do was in my AppDelegate, create a PlayerViewController with alloc init (because my AVPlayer is a static), and then pass on the remote event to it.